How do I retrieve the source code of a deployment on Cloud Run?
I need to retrieve the source code from a Google Cloud Run deployment. I have complete access to the deployments and I need to get back the code because it got wrangled up on my computer. How do I get it back?
So far, I have managed to get the image.tar and extract it but nothing useful is there in it.
Edit:
My code is a flask app with a main.py file and a bunch of html templates.

If your code is compiled code, then there is most likely no source code in the deployed images.

Unlike Cloud Functions where your source code is automatically uploaded to GCS as a zip file, Cloud Run does not keep your source code, as you are responsible for packaging your application and its dependencies into a container image before deployment.
